# package installed in python but not in my virtual conda enviroment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

l just installed `imgaug` https://github.com/aleju/imgaug as follow :

```
python2.7 setup.py sdist && sudo pip install dist/imgaug-0.2.1.tar.gz
```

However it doesn't work in my conda virtuel environment. Even if l installed ias follow

```
(/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv) ahmed@ahmed-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ git clone https://github.com/aleju/imgaug

(/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv) ahmed@ahmed-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ python2.7 setup.py sdist && sudo pip install dist/imgaug-0.2.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Try without using sudo on the Virtual environment

Comment: @crazyglasses, thank you it works. Why it didn't work with sudo ?

Comment: because sudo instalsl it system wide irrespective of whether you are within a virtualenv or not.